# Multiple Authentication classes Django doesn't try all the classes, fails at first

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'michan_api.utils.validators.ExampleAuthentication'
    ),
```

So I have this configured in my REST_FRAMEWORK setting in DRF. But it doesn't try all the classes.If the first one throws an exception it fails.

```
        for authenticator in self.authenticators:
            try:
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
            except exceptions.APIException:
                self._not_authenticated()
                raise
```

This piece of code is responsible for this. (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L373)

How do I make it try all the classes?

Comment: it does not make sense. You should use either jwt or token or basic&session based authentication. not all of them. Because mechanism wise, they are totally different

Comment: Agree, we use JWT mechanism for our existing systems. But due to some requirement we have to write a custom authentication (ExampleAuthentication) to verify another set of APIs by a different set of users. Not using Session/Basic/Token authentication.

Answer (score 3):

[Django REST framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) says:

> The method should return a two-tuple of (user, auth) if authentication succeeds, or None otherwise.
>
> In some circumstances instead of returning None, you may want to raise an AuthenticationFailed exception from the .authenticate() method.
>
> Typically the approach you should take is:
>
> - If authentication is not attempted, return None. Any other authentication schemes also in use will still be checked.
> - If authentication is attempted but fails, raise a AuthenticationFailed exception. An error response will be returned immediately, regardless of any permissions checks, and without checking any other authentication schemes.

According the to [`django-rest-framework-jwt`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/4021e0bd46eed8ca7dd0ea9337e2606951cb55fb/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L93-L99), it will *not* let you try another authentication if:

- your token is invalid
- your `Authorization` header does not match the syntax `Authorization: <string> <string>` with `<string>` being an actual string without whitespaces.

If your credentials do not meet that format, `django-rest-framework-jwt` will directly reject any authentication attempt. Depending on your requirements, you either need to fix your client credentials, either need to open an issue - or better open a pull request - on `django-rest-framework-jwt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Linovia. So, if I rearrange my auth classes and move the Custom Class before the JSONWebAuth class, that would also work if I handle it the way it's been mentioned in the docs.

Comment: most likely yes